# View which is the eth0 and eth1 (server, clients)

Tags: linux, unix, connection, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a client, server, and gateway running. How can I see which is using the eth0 and which is using the eth1?

ifconfig just shows all so I can't tell

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have different services bound to different interfaces on the same machine?

If so, netstat might be able to help identify what is listening and on which address:

```
[root@server~]# netstat -plunt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48007           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9923/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1575/master
```

Note the "Local Address" column in particular.